# Docker LVM plugin install issues

Tags: docker, go

im trying to install docker lvm plugin given in this link and when I execute the make command it throws me the following error.

```
pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ make
go-md2man -in man/docker-lvm-plugin.8.md -out docker-lvm-plugin.8
/usr/bin/go build -o docker-lvm-plugin .
utils.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system (from $GOROOT)
    /home/pr/programming/go/packages/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system (from $GOPATH)
driver.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers/volume" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers/volume (from $GOROOT)
    /home/pr/programming/go/packages/src/github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers/volume (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [lvm-plugin-build] Error 1
```

I believe its looking for docker go-plugin-helpers, I see those packages here but not sure how to install in my GOPATH.

https://github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build a Go program, you should read the [Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/), at least the basics. To install a package:

```
go get github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers
```

Comment: thanks..will look into the docs..It worked after I installed the actual packages.Now, I get this error - /home/pr/programming/go/packages/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system..Just wondering where I can find these related packages in Github..Is there a way to find it..

Comment: That's not an error, it's a path, but if the package is missing, you can `go get` it. The error should say the name of the package that's missing, not just the path where it's looking for it. It does seem like this makefile has serious issues; a good Go makefile will `go get` its own external dependencies. You can also cd to the root of the project (probably where the makefile is) and `go get ./...` to recursively get all dependencies for the project.

Comment: Good luck, and I'm sorry you ran into such a poorly written makefile :(